# angular ng-select how to set selected value by using template expression

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

angular ng-select how to set selected value by using a template. For example something like this,

```
<ng-select
          [options]="[{label : "first", value : "1"}, {label : "second", value : "2"}]"
          **[value]="'1'"**
          [multiple]="false">
</ng-select>
```

I am using angular2-select npm package. I would like to have the Input attribute do the task instead of ngModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution to this problem by wrapping ng-select component with custom component.

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'ice-select',
  templateUrl: './ice-select.component.html',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => IceSelectComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
```

And implemented interface methods for 'ControlValueAccessor' in component.

```
export class IceSelectComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {

      public writeValue(value: any) {
        this.selectedValue = value;
      }

      public registerOnChange(fn) {
        this.propagateChange = fn;
      }

      public registerOnTouched(fn){
        this.propagateTouched = fn;
      }
}
```

HTML template,

```
<ng-select
           [options]="options"
           [multiple]="false"
           [noFilter]="100"
           [allowClear]="true"
           [notFoundMsg]= "'No records found'"
           placeholder="Select"
           (selected)="onSelect($event)"
           (deselected)="onRemove($event)"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
></ng-select>
```

Comment: Can you please add more details? I am keen to know how you passed your data to 
[(ngModel)]= selectedValue

Comment: 'selectedValue' is in this case is a public variable defined inside 'IceSelectComponent'. The 'selectedValue' is being updated by 'writeValue' function which is being invoked by 'ControlValueAccessor' interface whenever form models change.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without using ngModel?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should to add bindValue input to be `bindValue="value"`